# MVC Route With *parameters Not Matching With Only One Argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to work with a route that will contain a variable number of arguments. The controller doesn't care much for these arguments so I'm happy to just get the lot.

The following route works in almost all cases:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Pdf",
            url: "Pdf/{reportName}/{*parameters}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Pdf", action = "Index" },
            namespaces: new string[1] { "Chd.Dms.Guides.Controllers" }
        );
```

So when I call any of the following URLs I hit my controller:

```
http://example/Pdf/SampleReport/Hello/World

http://example/Pdf/SampleReport/Hello/World/And/Universe
```

The problem is when it has the fewest number of arguments (just one additional one), it doesn't seem to match this route:

```
http://example/Pdf/SampleReport/Hello/
```

Why will it not catch this URL?

Comment: Do you have other routes defined _before_ this one? If you have the default one before, it will get matched with it.

Comment: Aha - exactly right. There was a call to a method setting up other routes first. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Didn't see your comment edit there and was still trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who encounter this problem, the route itself is absolutely correct - but you have to make sure there are no other routes that match declared before this one.

If there are other possible matching routes, you need to re-order them - or make them more specific so they don't both match.